# better way of printing data with same format

Tags: c

Is there a way in C where we can only specify the format output once and then use the printf statement. For example in the below code I want to print 10 decimal numbers and I know the format is %d for all 10 numbers. The numbers are not stored in an array otherwise I could have put the printf in a for loop. I wanted to know if there is a neater way of doing it.

```
printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Comment: You don't have to use a string literal, so you can do something like: `char const *fmt = "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n"'; /* ... */ printf(fmt, 1, 2, ...);`. Or you could wish for Fortran, where it would be something like `write(* '10I5'), ...`

Comment: Since all your numbers are constants why don't you use `printf("12345678910")`? Your numbers aren't actually constants? Then show us your real code, not made-up code.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a definite pattern as in your example, you can still use a loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    printf("%d", i);
printf("\n");
```

If there isn't, you should be using an array anyways.

Finally, if the issue is that you have a lot of literal numbers, then you can consider reading them from a data file instead of embedding them into your source file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way. Maybe you should store the numbers in a temporary array ...

```
{
    int numbers[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Of course that is more typing than just writing out `%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d`, but if you needed to expand to larger cases it would be useful.